Property of coordinate-wise convex function

A function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
coordinate-wise convex if  $f_x \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow
> \mathbb{R}, t \rightarrow f(x, t)$ and $f_y \colon \mathbb{R}
> \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \rightarrow f(t, y)$ are convex for any $x,
> y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that  $$\underline{\lim}\limits_{t
> \rightarrow 0+}  \frac{f(t, t) - f(0, 0)}{t} +
> \underline{\lim}\limits_{t \rightarrow 0-} \frac{f(0, 0) - f(t, t)}{t}
> \geq 0$$

I think this can be done by considering some $x, y$ and showing that
$$\underline{\lim}\limits_{t \rightarrow 0+}  \frac{f(x, t) - f(0, 0)}{t} + \underline{\lim}\limits_{t \rightarrow 0-} \frac{f(0, 0) - f(t, y)}{t} \geq 0$$
Then I can take a limit over $x, y$ and get the original claim. But I don't know how to write this down correctly (and if the idea is even correct). Thanks!
